# Unable to Crop Image from Gallery using CropIntent('com.android.camera.action.CROP')

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception, crop

Hello i am trying crop the image from Gallery and will display it in a ImageView.I getting NullPointerException in my **fileUri** ..Here i included my code..please have a look!

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView i1,i2;

    private final static int REQUEST_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 34;
    private static final int CAMERA_CODE = 101, GALLERY_CODE = 201, CROPING_CODE = 301;
    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private File outPutFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
       android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
       if (ab != null) {
           ab.hide();
       }
       i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prof1);
       i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prof2);
       i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImageOption();
           }
       });
    }
    private void selectImageOption() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Capture Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Details.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Capture Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp1.jpg");
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_CODE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Details.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            return;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, final @NonNull String[] permissions, final @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            System.out.println("Gallery Image URI : "+mImageCaptureUri);
            CropingIMG();
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            System.out.println("Camera Image URI : "+mImageCaptureUri);
            CropingIMG();
        } else if (requestCode == CROPING_CODE) {
            try {
                if(outPutFile.exists()){
                    Bitmap photo = decodeFile(outPutFile);
                    i1.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void CropingIMG() {
        final ArrayList<CropingOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropingOption>();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");
        ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =(ArrayList<ResolveInfo>)getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
        int size = list.size();
        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cann't find image croping app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 512);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outPutFile));
            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i   = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = (ResolveInfo) list.get(0);
                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                startActivityForResult(i, CROPING_CODE);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropingOption co = new CropingOption();
                    co.title  = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon  = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent= new Intent(intent);
                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }
                CropingOptionAdapter adapter = new CropingOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Croping App");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
//                        startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROPING_CODE);
                        CropingOption co =new CropingOption();
                        co=(CropingOption)cropOptions.get(item);
                        startActivityForResult(co.appIntent, CROPING_CODE);
                    }
                });
                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {
                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 512;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also i have use two Subclasses for Cropping an Image..

```
public class CropingOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private ArrayList mOptions;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CropingOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList options) {
        super(context, R.layout.cropping_selector, options);
        mOptions  = options;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cropping_selector, null);
        CropingOption item = (CropingOption) mOptions.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name)).setText(item.title);
            return convertView;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class CropingOption {
    public CharSequence title;
    public Drawable icon;
    public Intent appIntent;
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException in file..Also i have included my Error..please have a look

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=201, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://media/external/images/media/95419
>   typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/image flg=0x1 }} to activity
>   {com.company/com.company.Details}: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   file
>
> > Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
> >                                                                               at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
> >                                                                               at com.companyname.Details.CropingIMG(Details.java:144)
> >                                                                               at com.company.Details.onActivityResult(Details.java:109)

please have a look and Anyone give me a better Solution..Thanks in Advance

Comment: you do realize that "com.android.camera.action.CROP" is only available in devices with AOSP camera app, try to avoid it

Comment: AOSP camera App means.?

Comment: it is the stock android camera app, which may or may not be available in custom android builds, best recommendation is use any library to crop images

Comment: follow this and you will understand https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html